# HTML for sprites

Tags: html, css

So I've setup `Compass` for creating automatic sprites with `SCSS`. All goes well, it generates some nice CSS for me :-

```
.icons-sprite, .actions-new, .actions-edit, .actions-save, .actions-delete, .actions-refresh {
  background: url('/content/themes/admin/images/icons-s0336d5eb89.png') no-repeat;
}

.actions-new {
  background-position: 0 -48px;
}

... ... ...
```

Now I am creating a table, and in that table there is a "Action column" where you can perform functions on rows (delete or edit).

What is the generally accepted way (in html 5) for showing these buttons using sprites?

I've explored a few options and ran into a few problems

- `span` I can't get this to show unless I place it in `display: block` mode and if I do that it inserts new lines after the item, and I don't want to have to float everything
- `div` for some reason this one doesn't even show
- `img` The biggest issue I am seeing with this one is the requirement for a `src` field, this means that I need to duplictate the url over and over again.

What do other people use for sprites inside links?

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the markup you already have but if I understand correctly you're trying to place the span inside an `<a>` link? If so why not just attach the background image to the link and add padding and min-height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use span and `display: inline-block`. This will make the span behave like an image, so you can apply `vertical-align: middle`. Support goes all the way back to IE6 if you use it on an inline element.